# Heap allocation when passing by ref and instantiating new object

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var person = new Person();
Manipulate(ref person);
```

And the following method:

```
public void Manipulate(ref Person pObject)
{
    pObject = new Person();
}
```

Does the `Manipulate` method, when instantiating a new Person object, point to the same location on the Heap and create the pObject in that location, or does it create a new location on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

> The storage location of the object is passed to the method as the
>   value of the reference parameter. If you change the value in the
>   storage location of the parameter (to point to a new object), you also
>   change the storage location to which the caller refers.

To make it clear, check the below example:

```
static int[] array = new int[] { 5 };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var array2 = array;
    ModifyRef(ref array2);

    foreach (var item in array)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    foreach (var item in array2)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}

private static void ModifyRef(ref int[] array)
{
    array = new int[1];
    array[0] = 10;
}
```

Prints:

```
5
10
```

Making the pointer passed by reference refer to a new object doesn't mean that the old object is replaced. `array2` now points to a new memory location, but `array` still points to the same old array in memory.

Comment: `static int[] array = { 5 };` :|

Answer (score 2):

In some scenarios it doesn't make sense to create the object at the same memory location. If this happened, the the following code wouldn't work the way it does:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Person("Old name");
        var y = x;
        M(ref x);
        Console.WriteLine(y.Name); // Prints "Old name"

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void M(ref Person person)
    {
        person = new Person("New name");
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The old object with `Old name` property value would no longer exist, so you could not see `Old name` printed out. Since you do see it, two distinct objects exist at the same time.

In your example replacing the old object with a new one wouldn't break anything, but I doubt such checks are being performed, because there are probably a lot of distinct cases that would have to be taken into account when designing such a feature.